# 0 x 0 matrix when using pairwise t test

Tags: r, t-test, pairwise

I am trying to do a post-hoc test to compare different types of a variable (levels of pollution, which are coded as 1, 2 , 3). When I run the tests it gives me a "0 x 0 matrix" error.

```
p.none <- (d$pollute = 1)
p.i <- (d$pollute = 2)
p.m <- (d$pollute = 3)
pairwise.t.test(p.none, p.i, p.adj = "none")
pairwise.t.test(p.none, p.m, p.adj = "none")
```

here is the output of dput(d)

```
structure(list(tank.id = 1:60, condition = c("hot_species1", 
"cool_species1", "cool_species2", "cool_species1", "hot_species1", 
"hot_species2", "cool_species2", "hot_species1", "cool_species2", 
"cool_species1", "hot_species2", "hot_species1", "hot_species1", 
"hot_species1", "cool_species1", "cool_species2", "cool_species2", 
"cool_species2", "cool_species1", "hot_species2", "cool_species2", 
"cool_species2", "cool_species1", "cool_species1", "hot_species2", 
"cool_species1", "hot_species2", "hot_species2", "cool_species2", 
"hot_species2", "cool_species2", "hot_species2", "cool_species1", 
"hot_species1", "hot_species1", "cool_species1", "hot_species1", 
"hot_species2", "hot_species1", "hot_species1", "hot_species1", 
"hot_species1", "hot_species2", "cool_species2", "hot_species2", 
"cool_species1", "cool_species1", "hot_species2", "hot_species2", 
"cool_species2", "cool_species2", "hot_species2", "cool_species1", 
"hot_species1", "cool_species2", "cool_species1", "cool_species2", 
"hot_species1", "cool_species1", "hot_species2"), pollute = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), temp = c(2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), species = c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), light = c(1395L, 1347L, 
1408L, 1441L, 1371L, 1331L, 1418L, 1441L, 1407L, 1349L, 1392L, 
1365L, 1356L, 1465L, 1435L, 1420L, 1416L, 1364L, 1405L, 1423L, 
1411L, 1423L, 1380L, 1469L, 1421L, 1450L, 1412L, 1380L, 1407L, 
1416L, 1359L, 1363L, 1450L, 1377L, 1359L, 1412L, 1374L, 1459L, 
1371L, 1368L, 1397L, 1353L, 1404L, 1348L, 1395L, 1373L, 1380L, 
1440L, 1376L, 1400L, 1351L, 1348L, 1430L, 1432L, 1387L, 1374L, 
1388L, 1410L, 1460L, 1388L), density = c(218L, 257L, 227L, 251L, 
213L, 161L, 250L, 208L, 222L, 214L, 223L, 244L, 203L, 235L, 241L, 
255L, 260L, 210L, 284L, 242L, 252L, 324L, 230L, 229L, 191L, 314L, 
218L, 240L, 297L, 228L, 290L, 328L, 321L, 242L, 200L, 269L, 188L, 
199L, 244L, 196L, 234L, 128L, 252L, 239L, 250L, 284L, 209L, 305L, 
288L, 193L, 201L, 318L, 262L, 222L, 207L, 253L, 295L, 229L, 326L, 
162L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -60L))
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(d)` in order to make your error reproducible.

Comment: the output of dput(d) has been added @Phil

Comment: It's not clear on what you are comparing across the pollute levels, maybe you are looking for something like `pairwise.t.test(d$light, d$pollute, p.adjust.method = "none")`?

Comment: These are my instructions: Perform two post-hoc tests (uncorrected with pooled variance), testing each kind of pollution against the control condition @Phil